# Why would JavaScript Promises sometimes neither use .catch nor use .then?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

This could be a question with a zillion answers or you'll otherwise need to see my actual code to help me. And it could be that there's one cause (or a small number of causes) for the behavior I'm seeing. First question: Which is it? If the former, I'll withdraw the question so people don't waste their time. I cannot share the code and it's longer than is appropriate here anyway.

I'm writing JavaScript in Node.JS using bluebird for Promises. Parts of my code fit this model.

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
function a() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    <... do something>
    <either> return resolve();
    <or> return reject();
  })
}

a()
.catch(error => { console.log('Used .catch   error=', error) })
.then(result => { console.log('Used .then   result=', result) });
```

In *some* parts of my code fitting this model, I see the results of one of the log statements. In *other* parts of my code fitting this model, I see neither. In the latter parts, when I trace execution path with the debugger, after it finishes with `a`, it puts the green highlight on `(error` in `.catch(error => {` and `next` on `}` closing a Promise that contains `a`, its `.then`, and its `.catch`, and `next` (after going through some bluebird code) on `}` closing a function that contains that same Promise.

JSHint doesn't identify anything related.

I saw very similar behavior when I was using native Promises. I solved it then by substituting bluebird Promises. Now I see bluebird doing the same, though in different places.

If this is something with a known and easily described cause, I'll really appreciate the help. If it's bigger than that, this question probably doesn't belong on Stack Overflow; I'll withdraw it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your question "why would one write asynchronous code that doesn't return"? It's likely for back-end triggers that don't need a return, such as logging the user's actions.

Comment: Nope. Thanks, though. It's more like: If I call a function that contains a promise (`a` above), shouldn't the execution path _always_ go through the appropriate `.then` after `return resolve()` and _always_ go through the appropriate `.catch` after `return reject()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, let's start with something completely different. [Chances are you should never be using the promise constructor, ever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

The promise constructor is for converting things that are not promise returning into things that are promise returning. If you're using bluebird, you should be using `Promise.promisifyAll` to do that swiftly and efficiently for you.

Promises are about making your life *easier* not *harder*. Writing a ton of boilerplate would beat this purpose. It is likely some frustrating is caused from incorrectly converting a callback API. This is hard to get right - for example, the promise constructor completely ignores `return` values.

Your code uses `catch` which *recovers* from errors. A little like:

```
try {
    var result = doSomething();
} catch (error) {
   console.log('Used .catch   error=', error);
}
console.log('Used .then   result=', result);
```

Using `.catch` means you *recover* from the errors. It means your code can gracefully handle exceptional conditions. If you need to signal in a `catch` that your code does *not* recover from the error - you need to rethrow the exception:

```
.catch(e => { console.log("Got ", e); throw e; })
```

Since you're using bluebird and modern Node - might I suggest taking a look at generators? http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.coroutine.html

Comment: Some will consider this more a discussion than a Q&A. Might you consider joining me at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103327/javascript-promises? I'd love to pick your brain!